# Google Chrome refusing to open pages in Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I'm running Google Chrome on Windows 10, latest editions. Chrome refuses to open any pages, returning "Aw snap" error messages. To resolve this I've:

1. Removed all extensions.
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome.
3. Tried Chrome on a different user.
4. Ran Chrome Cleanup Tool.
5. Deleted my Google folder in Appdata.
6. Incognito pages don't work either.

None of these worked. Firefox at all times is working perfectly so its not an internet problem.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is likely that malware is trying (and failing) to modify the page that is loading. I've also seen this as a symptom of machines that had nasty redirect malware removed, as the redirects that the malware creates no longer have anywhere to resolve.

I highly recommend a fresh Windows 10 install, only way to be sure you're fully free of whatever may have infected your current Windows installation.

Comment: A fresh install of Windows is extreme. I solved my problem by performing a full system scan using Windows Defender, uninstalling Chrome and using windows explorer to search for and delete all files containing "google" or "chrome".

Comment: @Mowing Bar is right. It will work but it is the last option. You should recommend first to instal any antimalware solution or similar to clean the computer and then retry. It is like: "Purchase a new laptop and it should not happen..."

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps, to resolve "Aw snap" error messages with Chrome browser.

**Steps To Resolve:**

- Go to Chrome shortcut in the Desktop (If not exists create one)
- Right click -> Properties
- In the target field, At the end add a space followed by the below **-no-sandbox**
- Apply-Ok
- Launch chrome using the shortcut

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

1. Go to windows task manager
2. go to details tab
3. kill all the chrome process
4. run the chrome it will open